# converting python nested-list into matlab-cell using matlab engine

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert a python nested-list into a matlab-cell in python. My python nested-list contains only strings.

This is my list:

```
x = [['a', 'b'],['d','e']]                                                                                                 

type(x)                                                                                                                    
list
```

This was my attempt to pass it as matlab cell:

```
import matlab.engine 
import matlab 
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab() 
y = eng.cell(x)                                                                                                            
type(y)                                                                                                                    
list
```

This approach **fails**, since the type of y is still a list.

Another attempt with an **error**:

```
y = eng.cellstr(x)
Error using cellstr (line 44)
Element 1 is not a string scalar or character array. All elements of cell input must be 
string scalars or character arrays.
```

Any suggestion here is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Any updates? ....

Comment: Hi @Paolo,
apologies for the silence.


Actually, I need to wrap a matlab function (**f_matlab**) inside python. The input of **f_matlab** is a matlab cell structure. It would look like this:

 **x_mat** =   
 
2×2 cell array

    {'a'}    {'b'}
    {'c'}    {'d'}
`
However, wrapping **f_matlab** inside python as eng.f_matlab(eng.cell(x)) fails. Because **eng.cell(x)** is not the same as **x_mat**. Its size and elements are different. This is my struggle ;)

Answer (score 0):

*This approach fails, since the type of y is still a list.*

That's just what the cell representation looks like in Python, but in reality that is a cell in MATLAB. You can confirm this by running a cell specific operation like `cell2mat`:

```
>>> import matlab.engine 
>>> import matlab

>>> eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()     
>>> x = [['a', 'b'],['d','e']]
>>> matlab_cell = eng.cell(x)
>>> eng.cell2mat(matlab_cell[0])
'ab'
```

so `matlab_cell` is a cell for MATLAB:

```
>>> eng.iscell(matlab_cell)
True
```

but it is shown as a list in Python:

```
>>> type(matlab_cell)
<class 'list'>
```

You can find more information on the implicit conversion the engine does [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html).